# Creating a custom keyboard

Tags: java, android, button, keyboard

I'm designing a game with a custom keyboard(Rows of buttons) I want the buttons to input text into the Edittext. Is it possible? 
For example: I want button 1 to input character "a" into EditText1.
Thanks in Advance! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_a);
EdiText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

OnClickListener aClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    String current = et.getText().toString();
    et.setText(current + "a");
  }
};    

a.setOnClickListener(aClickListener);
```

If you are wanting to implement an entire keyboard this way, I would advise a different direction.

Answer (score 0):

Get the click event of the button, in onClick() handler, set the text on the edittext whatever you desire .for ex:

if u clicked button A,

```
public void  onClick(View v){
e1.setText("a");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do this.

```
et.dispatchKeyEvent( new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A ) );
```

Each possible key has a constant keyEvent.KEYCODE. This does work better in some cases for entering text as opposed to setting/appending text to an editbox, as it makes handling cursor position much easier